# Unit test can not pass

Tags: java

I have the program which make division.
I need to print division to the screen, I did It and on the screen everything the same but unit test still fails..

[image]

Below the class that print It :

```
 private String drawResultForDividentThatEqualsZero(StringBuilder result, Integer divisor) {
    result.append("_0").append(SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR).append(divisor.toString()).append("\n");
    result.append(" 0").append(SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR).append("-").append("\n");
    result.append(" -").append(SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR).append("0").append("\n");
    result.append(" 0");

    return result.toString();
}
```

And some code :

```
 public static final String SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR = "|";

 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```

The test which does not pass :

```
@Test
public void Should_MakeDivision_When_DividentEqualsZero() {
    String expected = "_0│100\n" +
            " 0│-\n" +
            " -│0\n" +
            " 0";
    assertEquals(expected, numbersDivision.makeDivision(0, 100));
}
```

Main method makeDivision :

```
public String makeDivision(int introducedDividend, int introducedDivisor) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder reminder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor = new StringBuilder("0.");
    StringBuilder lastReminderNumber = new StringBuilder();


    int dividend = Math.abs(introducedDividend);
    int divisor = Math.abs(introducedDivisor);
    checkExceptions(divisor);

    Integer divisorMuplipliedByQuotient = 0;
    Integer reminderInInteger = 0;
    Integer newReminder = 0;

    String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");

    mainMethodForCalculateDivision(dividend, divisor, digits, reminderInInteger, reminder, divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, result, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor,
            newReminder, lastReminderNumber);
    return result.toString();
}
```

And the main work class for this case :

```
private String mainMethodForCalculateDivision(Integer dividend, int divisor, String[] digits, Integer reminderInInteger, StringBuilder reminder, Integer divisorMuplipliedByQuotient,
                                              StringBuilder result, StringBuilder quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, StringBuilder quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor,
                                              Integer newReminder, StringBuilder lastReminderNumber) {
    if (dividend == 0) {
        drawResultForDividentThatEqualsZero(result, divisor);
        return result.toString();
    }
    if (dividend >= divisor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            calculateDivisionWhenDividentMoreOrEqualsDivisor(reminder, digits, i, divisor, divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, dividend,
                    result, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor, newReminder, lastReminderNumber);
        }
        improveResultViewing(dividend, divisor, result, quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, lastReminderNumber,
                reminderInInteger);
        return result.toString();
    }
    checkIfDividentEqualsZeroOrLessThanDivisorAndCalculate(dividend, divisor, reminder, reminderInInteger, digits, divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, newReminder, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor,
            quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor, result, lastReminderNumber);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your method returns a `StringBuilder`, but you are comparing it with a `String`. Replace `makeDivision(0, 100)` with `makeDivision(0, 100).ToString())`.

Comment: Did you try comparing the string to another strong instead of a StringBuilder?

Comment: Include your method in the post : 'numbersDivision.makeDivision(0, 100)'

Comment: @beatrice Added it.

Comment: @npinti It doesn't help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Symbols in "expected" and in "SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BET" are different.